# Why `bytesN` elements padded to the right, but all other elements (e.g. `uintN`) are padded to the left?

Tags: abi

here is the great post how to encode arguments to ethereum functions https://medium.com/b2expand/abi-encoding-explanation-4f470927092d

But WHY ethereum creators decided to pad like this?

[image]